# Using CSS Selector To Fetch Text After a Closing Span

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML generated by Angular CLI (I am new to both Selenium and Angular):

```
<ul class="projects">
  <li *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{project.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{project.id}}</span> {{project.projectName}}
    </a>
    <button class="delete" title="delete project"
    (click)="delete(project)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to retrieve the text represented by the string project.projectName that follows the closing span. So far I've tried:

```
String foundProjectName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("// 
[@class='projects']/li")).getText();
```

which returns the project.id, the project.projectName, **and** a "x". Also,

```
String foundProjectName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.badge + 
span")).getText();
```

which returns the project.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the outer text that contains both the ID and name and then remove the inner text that contains only the ID... which leaves the name.

```
String outer = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.projects a")).getText(); // project.id project.projectName
String inner = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.badge")).getText(); // project.id
String projectName = outer.replace(inner, "").trim();
System.out.println(projectName);
```